How to get the parent process id from the subprocess in Frends
I have a sub process, that is  being used by many parent processes. Requirement is to log the parent process link when the execution hits the subprocess. But I am only able to access the process ID of the sub process, I need a way to find the same of the parent one.
One thing that I can do, is pass the parent process ID from the parent to the subprocess, and then log it. But we have lot of process that is using this subprocess, so it will be tedious to do this for all process. So is there any other way?

No. You have to pass the execution ID of the parent process to the subprocess via parameters, to be able to access it in the subprocess.
I think you can set the default value to be {{#process.executionid}} for the new parameter. So that way you don't have to write it by hand to every calling process. You still need to make a new save/version of the process and deploy it.

Ossi is correct, you can set the process variable to {{ #process.id }} and you don't have to manually add that variable every time you create a subprocess call
example of trigger variable default value in subprocess
This is the only way to do it at the moment
